# Problem with ng-bootstrap 14 tooltip in angular 15

Tags: angular, tooltip, ng-bootstrap

I'm upgrading an Angular project from 14 to 15, including ng-bootstrap from 13.1.1 to 14.1.0.

For the most part, the upgrade has gone smoothly, except for an issue around the tooltip component in ng-bootstrap. I've created a skinnied-down Stackblitz to demonstrate the problem:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fagut4

The issue appears to be this. If I create a component (standalone or otherwise) that has an ngbTooltip call inside of it, like this very simple example:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbTooltipModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-tooltip-test',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [NgbTooltipModule],
  template: `
  <span [ngbTooltip]="tooltipText">HOVER ME</span>`,
})
export class NgbdTooltipTest {
  @Input() tooltipText!: string;
}
```

...and then I try call that component from a parent, like this:

```
before<ngbd-tooltip-test tooltipText="here is a tooltip"></ngbd-tooltip-test
  >text after
```

...then on hover, the `after` text is wrapping to the next line. This behavior didn't happen in Angular 14/ng-bootstrap 13.1.1.

The Stackblitz example has a root element of `span`, but I have changed it to both `a` and `button`, and I'm seeing the same results.

Either I'm missing something really silly here, or this is just broken now. Anybody else experiencing this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had problems like the before, so much so that I've gotten into the habit of automatically adding the attribute `container="body"` any time I use to *ngbTooltip* directive.  Doing just that to your example made the problem going away.  Alternatively to adding an attribute to each usage, this value can be set globally using the *NgbTooltipConfig* service.

If this isn't possible, I found after some experimentation that setting the css *display* property of the *host* element to *contents* also does this trick.

This could give a clue as to the issue, as initially the host's *display* property was *inline*.  Given that the element added by the tooltip directive is a *block* element, an issue could be caused with rendering since inline elements aren't supposed to include block elements... though, I really can't say for sure if this is the case.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-tooltip-test',
  standalone: true,
  styles: [':host { display: contents; }'],
  imports: [NgbTooltipModule],
  template: `
  <span [ngbTooltip]="tooltipText" [closeDelay]="600000">HOVER ME</span>`,
})
```

Comment: Oh, FFS. Thanks for this. I suppose the mystery is still why this worked pre-upgrade and now doesn’t.

Comment: What's especially annoying about this is ng-bootstrap's documentation says nothing about the layout of the wrapped element being affected by the presence of absence of `container="body"`--only the tooltip itself.